# how to connect to database in c #?

Tags: ado.net

good, I'm learning c # .net, what is my error in this query? , I want to consume the get service and it gives me a connection error. I thank you in advance I want to learn to program to start in the world of programming

```
 [HttpGet("buscar/{id}")]
        public ActionResult buscar(int id)
        {
            string cn =
        "Data Source=192.168.1.16;Initial Catalog=ProjectCondominio;Integrated User = ebim; Password = Viernes14";


            string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MPERSONAS" +
                "WHERE MPERS_ID = @idpersona";

            using (SqlConnection cmd = new SqlConnection(cn))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cmd);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idpersona", id);
               
                    cmd.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                return Ok(reader);
            }

        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtwuY.png)

Comment: What type of database are you connecting to? "Keyword not supported" means that the connection string contains a term that is not recognised by the connection. Where did you get this connection string? [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring) lists the allowed connection parameters for SQL Server. "Integrated User" is not in it, so this is probably what it is complaining about.

Comment: Good friend, thank you very much, now I get an error Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near' = '.', how do I solve this ?, thanks for your help crack

Comment: Just a hunch but I think with your concatenated query you may be missing a space, so you're feeding the connection `...FROM dbo.MPERSONASWHERE...` - note lack of space.

Comment: Thanks friend, please how can I contact you, in case I have another problem, you would really help me a lot

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  If you're new to programming, you might find this post on debugging small programs helpful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ (it helped me anyway).

Comment: Please dont use comments for answers - i just noticed i wrote whole answer for the same thing as Tom W wrote in comments... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MPERSONAS" +
                "WHERE MPERS_ID = @idpersona";
```

will concatenate to

```sql
SELECT * FROM dbo.MPERSONASWHERE MPERS_ID = @idpersona
```

which is not valid sql. Add space on end of first or start of second line. Or use `@` and keep your query with ReturnCharacter like this:

```cs
string query = @"SELECT * FROM dbo.MPERSONAS
                 WHERE MPERS_ID = @idpersona";
```

---

Also (not in question, but let me tell you anyway) dont use "naked" SqlCommand & returning whole DataReader:

Imagine what would happen when you add new column to your `dbo.MPERSONAS` - your API will change as side effect, exposing this new column. Maybe you expose some PPI (Protected Personal Information) or `dbo.MPERSONAS.CreditCardNumber` or whatever.

Use strongly typed DTO (i have no idea which version of .net are you using, so maybe new `record` (.net5+) or good old `class`) + some kind of ORM, like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) (if you want to write your queries by hand - StackOverflow is running on Dapper ;) ) or EntityFramework(Core).